# Show image based on label - jQuery Datatables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I'm trying to show images based on some labels with `jQuery` datatables.

```
               <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?=$row['IP']?></td>
                        <td><?=$row['Agent']?></td>
                        <td><?=$row['Verified']?></td>

                        if($row['Label'] == "Other"){
                        <td><img src="imgb.png"></td>
                        }
                        else{
                        <td><img src="imgc.png"></td>
                        }

                    </tr>
                 <?php
                }
                ?>
```

The problem is the 'if part' is not working, it just show all the two images.
And also it echo following.

```
if($row['Label'] == "Other"){ } else{ } if($row['Label'] == "OtherCrawler"){ } else{ } if($row['Label'] == "OtherCrawler"){ } else{ }
```

What is wrong here?. Please consider I'm bit new to php/jQuery.

Comment: You're still "in PHP" when you're doing `if($row['Label'] == "Other"){<td><img src="imgb.png"></td>` you need to echo that. I.e.: `echo '<td><img src="imgb.png"></td>';`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think it's opposite to what you say. The OP forgot to declare php.

Comment: Yes, you're right. @PoomrokcThe3years

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did not mean to be rude , man. It's just for fun. Sorry if you think I'm rude.

Comment: @Nilani Algiriyage where you have used JQuery in this? as this contains PHP & HTML only

Comment: I did not take it as rude @PoomrokcThe3years there's no problem here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to start php tags before and after if

`<?php
    if($row['Label'] == "Other"){
    ?>
    <td><img src="imgb.png"></td>
    <?php 
    } else{
    ?>
    <td><img src="imgc.png"></td>
    <?php 
    }
?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
            <?php
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$row['IP']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['Agent']?></td>
                    <td><?=$row['Verified']?></td>
                  <?php
                    if($row['Label'] == "Other"){
                  ?>
                    <td><img src="imgb.png"></td>
                <?php  }
                    else{
                    <td><img src="imgc.png"></td>
                    }
                  ?>
                </tr>
             <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Above answer is for image display when it returns using
>   while/for-each loop from the database. But when we are using
>   ssp.customized.class file then it will be not in use.